# How to build a Hybrid app to view customized Google analytics reports

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a website in which I have implemented Google Analytics and now I'm trying to build a Hybrid app to view the customized GA report in it with some notification options.

Is there any plugins available to view GA report through my app with graphs?

Comment: Refer this link it worked for me in Ionic -framework [link](https://github.com/ggendre/GALocalStorage).. if it will not work means i will upload a demo project for you